# Can't update RecyclerView through AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to view list of IP address in the local network, but I'm doing something wrong because I couldn't update the RecyclerView after the list of IP's is ready.
Here is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
String light_names[];
int icon[] = {R.drawable.light_icon};
IPListAdapter ipListAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    light_names = new String[]{"Detecting.."};
    ipListAdapter = new IPListAdapter(this, light_names, icon);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(ipListAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    new getIps().execute();
    ipListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private class getIps extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    String[] all_ips;
    int counter;
    int onsetCounter;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //count
        counter = 0;

        try {
            Enumeration nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while(nis.hasMoreElements())
            {
                NetworkInterface ni = (NetworkInterface) nis.nextElement();
                Enumeration ias = ni.getInetAddresses();
                while (ias.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    InetAddress ia = (InetAddress) ias.nextElement();
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {

        }

        all_ips = new String[counter+1];

        // getting count
         onsetCounter = 0;

        try {
            Enumeration nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while(nis.hasMoreElements())
            {
                NetworkInterface ni = (NetworkInterface) nis.nextElement();
                Enumeration ias = ni.getInetAddresses();
                while (ias.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    InetAddress ia = (InetAddress) ias.nextElement();
                    String s = ia.getHostAddress();
                    if(s!=null){
                        all_ips[onsetCounter] = s;
                    }else{
                        all_ips[onsetCounter] = "s";
                    }

                    onsetCounter++;
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        light_names = all_ips;

        ipListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

Here is the IPListAdapter class:

```
public class IPListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IPListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

String data1[];
int images[];
Context context;

public IPListAdapter(Context ct, String s1[], int img[] ){
    context= ct;
    data1 = s1;

    images = img;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.myText1.setText((data1[position]));
    holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[0]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data1.length;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView myText1;
    ImageView myImage;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.light_name);
        myImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    }
}
}
```

I feel like the problem is mainly from the way I update the adapter in onPostExecute. I tried adding a textview and setting its value inside onPostExecute and it worked well, but the recycler view wouldn't update.

Comment: `light_names = all_ips;` That should be: `ipListAdapter.data1 = all_ips;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @blackapps mentioned in the comment you are giving a copy of your IP-list to the Adapter-class when you instantiate the adatper. In your `onPostExecute` you only update the list of the activity, but the adapters `data` field is not changed.